# Limit number of lines shown at a time by running command

Tags: macos, terminal

I have a few commands I am running in terminal that output everything they do, which is great, but I don't need my entire window filled with thousands of lines of input.  Is there is way to make only the last x number of lines outputted show, and the rest are removed?

Comment: Why not just make the window smaller? Don't you every want to scroll back to earlier messages?

Comment: I am just interested in seeing that it is still working on something, but I don't need the entire history buffer filled with it's work

Comment: But how does it being able to see it hurt you?

Comment: @reinierpost I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: It takes effort to remove the other lines - it takes next to no effort to ignore them, so why bother?

Comment: Because if I want to look back at something else I might have thousands of lines to scroll through.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tail command. It will list just the last few lines of a file, specified by the user. If will also list just last few lines in real time if desired. tail -n 5 will print last 5 lines. Just do man tail to get other options.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which commands you're seeing much output for I can say that you can limit the amount of lines outputted on the terminal with the tail command by using a "pipe" to send the output of the 1st command to the 2nd command. An example would be:

```
ls | tail -n 5
```

Instead of sending the output of the ls command to the screen it sends (or pipes) it to the tail command. The tail command here will print the last 5 lines of the ls output due to "-n 5" being specified.

Comment: This will only display the *final* 5 lines. @traisjames wants to see *all* of the `ls` output scroll by with a window size of 5.

Answer (score 0):

Console output is just lines written one by one to an output stream (standard output or standard error). Console windows and terminal applications just display those, scrolling the previous ones upwards.  They cannot erase any lines already printed.  You need, either:

1. A console / terminal application with the built-in capability of omitting all but the last *n* lines when redrawing upon receiving a new line; this may be possible, but I don't know how.
2. An additional application that can do this, started from the console as a wrapper for your application; `screen` and `tmux` can probably do it, but I don't know how.
3. An application that can do this to which you pipe the console output of your application; `multitail` will fit here, for instance:

   ```
   find | env LINES=10 multitail -j
   ```

   will display the output of `find`, never showing more than 10 lines at once.

You haven't stated the OS you're on, but `multitail` is available for Linux, e.g. as an Ubuntu package.